# WP7 Background Audio Player play

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

In the [Background Audio Player sample architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394039%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), the BackgroundAudioPlayer is used to send command to Zune Media Queue and can be used by both Application UI & BackgroundPlayerAgent

However, when I call

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = audioTrack1;

BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play()
```

in the Application UI, it doesnot play.

It seems the `Play` method only works in the agent.

Why is that ?

Comment: It should work. Are you getting an error? Got a repro?

Comment: @MattLacey I mean Instance.Play() in UI part only trigger UserAction event in the agent part. And Instance.Play() in agent part actually make the audio played. It seem a little weird